# Spring MVC: exchange or postForEntity

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Is there any difference between the two lines of code below? Why should I use one instead of the other? They both work great, I just wish to understand why they both exist if they do the same thing.

```
return restTemplate.exchange(messagingFullUrl, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, JsonResponse.class);
```

and

```
return restTemplate.postForEntity(messagingFullUrl, requestEntity, JsonResponse.class);
```

Comment: ResponseEntity<JsonResponse>

Comment: They both return ResponseEntity<T> and my method's return is ResponseEntity<JsonResponse>. That's why I am able to use both the lines mentioned above without any other change.

Comment: Oops, sorry. I was thinking of `postForObject`. `postForEntity` (and its equivalents for other HTTP methods) is just a convenience method. In the background, they're both implemented the same way.